# How to choose which associated models to return in a query with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, has-many

I have the following code in my model:

```
var $name = 'Product';            
    var $hasMany = array(
        'AttachedProduct' => array(
            'className'     => 'AttachedProduct',
            'foreignKey'    => 'product_id'
        ),
        'Sale' => array(
            'className'     => 'Sale',
            'foreignKey'    => 'item_id',
            'fields'    => 'Sale.peso_value'
        )
    );
```

I want to use the `Sale` part only. Currently when I query my Products model the 'AttachedProduct' is also returned. I want only the `Sale` records to be returned.

Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationships in a model like `hasMany` and `belongsTo` are just possible definitions. You can choose which ones you want to return when doing a `find()` with something called the [Containable behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html). Check out the docs for details.

You start by adding the behavior to your `Product` model:

```
class Product extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');  // add this line
    ...
}
```

Then when you want to query for your Products, you put the `hasMany` relationships that you want to return in the `contain()` method before the `find()`.

```
$this->Product->contain('Sales');
$products = $this->Product->find('all', ...);
```

Then you'll only have the Products and associated Sales.

Comment: You can also combine the contain() with the query itself:

$products = $this->Product->find('all', array('contain'=>array('Sales')));

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `unbindModel` to remove the unwanted relation on the fly. Which data we do not wish to retrieve.

```
$this->Product->unbindModel(
   array('hasMany' => array('Sale'))    
);
```

For more information please check this [book.cakephp link](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1045/Creating-and-Destroying-Associations-on-the-Fly)